# How to center only the div around images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some images that I want to align inside a div with a given size.

Problem: I'd like to center the images *horizontally*. If they don't fit in a single row, I want the images to stack, but only the div around the should be centered horizontally. The images themselves should always align to the left.

Example:

```
<div id="parent" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; text-align:center; width: 280px;border:1px solid black;">
    <div id="wrapper" style="margin: 10px; border: 2px solid red; display:inline-block;">
        <img src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png" width="100px" />
        <img src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png" width="100px" />
        <img src="http://blog.room34.com/wp-content/uploads/underdog/logo.thumbnail.png" width="100px" />
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dccyy47r/14/

Here you see a linebreak as the 3 images don't fit in one row. I'd like to have image 1 + 3 to be on top of each other. Further, the div around the images should horizontally align in the middle.

If I change the alignment to `text-align: left`, the images are aligned left as expected, BUT the `wrapper` div around the images does not center the whole image content.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Center your div (remove `display:inline-block`) :

```
#parent {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Float your images and add some spacing to make it look nice

```
#wrapper img {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 6px 6px 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dccyy47r/13/

Comment: I don't want to center the black div inside the page. I want to center the images *inside* the red div, but still keep the 1.+3. image on top of each other. Thus, having equal space from the left or right border to the images contained. But not having the 3rd image align to center, but left and below the top image.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But without having to give the exact width of the `wrapper`, as the images should dynamically fill the `parent` (which has a known width).

Comment: it won't work easily without specifying a width. Can't you determine how many images are being added and then update the width? and what should it do if you have like 10 images. Should it fill up the entire space and then go to the second line?

Comment: I can ensure all images have the same width, but I don't know the width before. So I always want to distribute all images one after the other. No matter how many lines it may require. I also never know how many images are to be added.